# Saving and Reloading a ydata-profiling / pandas-profiling ProfileReport object for later use

Tags: python, pandas-profiling, data-profiling

I am using the ydata-profiling library to generate profile reports of my pandas DataFrame. I would like to save the entire ProfileReport object, so I can load it later without having to regenerate the report.

**Questions**:

Is there a way to serialize the entire ProfileReport object for later use?
If not, is there a recommended way to save the generated profile (maybe as JSON or another format) and later load it back as a ProfileReport object, so I can manipulate or view it?

I tried serializing the object using pickle, but encountered issues as it appears some internal components of the report are not serializable.

I also considered saving the report as a JSON and loading it back, but there doesn't seem to be a direct method to convert a saved JSON report back into a ProfileReport object.

Here's a simple setup for context:

```
profile = ProfileReport(df)
```

Saving the report as JSON

```
profile.to_file("report.json")
```

Attempt to load the report from JSON
(This will throw an error because `from_json` is not a recognized method)

```
profile_json = ProfileReport.from_json("report.json")
```

This line will cause an error

```
profile_json.to_file("profile_json.html")
```

Serializing the profile report using pickle

```
output_path = "profile.pkl"
with open(output_path, 'wb') as ppfile: 
    pickle.dump(profile, ppfile)
```

Deserializing the profile report from pickled file:

```
with open(output_path, 'rb') as ppfile:
    profile_pp = pickle.load(ppfile)
    profile_pp.to_file("profile_pp.html")
```

Comment: i tried dill package aslo. as import dill as pickle. Still same issue

Can't pickle Unsupported: it's not found as ydata_profiling.model.typeset.typeset_types.<locals>.Unsupported

Comment: tried using 
https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling/blob/master/src/ydata_profiling/serialize_report.py

i am able to dump the profile as serialized object, but when loading back , its a differen type:

original profile type:  'ydata_profiling.profile_report.ProfileReport'>


after loading from saved picke object, its below type, which doesnt have to_file methods
<class 'ydata_profiling.report.presentation.core.root.Root

'Root' object has no attribute 'to_file'

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to save and load with existing dump and load methods. But cant use it for compare because

if not all(is_df_available):
--> 187             raise ValueError("Reports where not initialized with a DataFrame.")

```
profile = ProfileReport(df, config_file=config_to_use)    
profile.dump(output_profile_pp)    
loaded_profile = ProfileReport()  # Create an empty instance
loaded_profile.load(output_profile_pp)
print(type(loaded_profile))  # Should print <class 'ydata_profiling.profile_report.ProfileReport'> 
loaded_profile.to_file("loaded_report.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling/issues/1247) worked for me:

```py
profile = ProfileReport(df,)
profile.to_file('report.html')  # Trigger the computation / alternative you can use profile.to_json() for no file output
profile.dump('my_report') # Serialize in pickle to my_report.pp

loaded_profile = ProfileReport().load('my_report.pp')  # notice that you have to instantiate an empty instance of ProfileReport

loaded_profile.df = df.head(1)  # or empty but with the columns + proper dtypes
```